# Perform Get request with body - Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, request

I'm trying to perform a GET request to elastic search api 
which is needed in this form

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "more_like_this" : {
            "fields" : ["title", "description"],
            "like" : "Once upon a time",
            "min_term_freq" : 1,
            "max_query_terms" : 12
        }
    }
}
```

I used [request](https://github.com/request/request)
But I can't find how to add body to the request.

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the document about [request(options, callback)](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback)

Also, `GET` method should't send any body, please confirm it's not `POST`.

```
request.get('http://localhost:8092/_search', {
  json: true,
  body: {
    "query": {
        "more_like_this" : {
            "fields" : ["title", "description"],
            "like" : "Once upon a time",
            "min_term_freq" : 1,
            "max_query_terms" : 12
        }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: API is really GET method, it's works but weird. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/_the_search_api.html

Comment: yes the GET request not recommended with body but it's happened :D 
BTW i was missing the `json: true,`

Comment: More about `GET` with body at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Answer (score 0):

If you use `GET`, you can't have body, you just have query.
You can convert your query to string and add to your url, or use option with `qs`:

```
option = {
    url: 'your_url',
    qs: your_query
};
request(option, (error,res)=>{});
```

If want use body, you should use `POST`.

Answer (score -1):

Hi have you tried simply passing your body as a second argument to your request?

```
request.get('yourEndpoint', { // your body })
```

Comment: i did it before but it was missing a param

Answer (score -1):

You can not add body to a get request, you will have to add a query string for the request to send those data.

Comment: GET can take body with the request, Thanks for your effort.